# replace quotes and everything inside until an un-escaped quote is available

Tags: php

I'm trying to develop a real time text formatter within **PHP** and **Ajax**, and it's all going well so far. However, I have come across an issue which I cannot seem to figure out.

Basically, what I want to happen is, let's say I have these three strings:

```
"This is some text \" (and a double quote)"
'This is some text \' (and a single quote)'
"This is some more text"
```

I would like it to become:

```
<span id="ff3814">"This is some text \" (and a double quote)"</span>
<span id="ff3814">'This is some text \' (and a single quote)'</span>
<span id="ff3814">"This is some more text"</span>
```

Notice how the `span` doesn't close off until there is a ***un-escaped quote** (of the same type as the opening quote)*.

I have tried doing something along the lines of this using **Regex**:

```
$output = 'Other content... "This is some text \" (and a double quote)"'. 

$output = preg_replace('/"[^"]+"/', "<span id='ff3814'>$1</span>", $output);
// should output: Other content... <span id='ff3814'>"This is some text \" (and a double quote)"</span>
```

However, it would only ever output the `span` tag and none of the actual content. Not only that, I soon realized it would not work on *un-escaped quotes* anyway.

How would I get this functionality? I haven't found anything close to it on the first or second pages of **Google**, and there doesn't seem to be any **StackOverflow** posts with the same request.

All help is appreciated, 
Cheers.

Comment: why can't you just do  $output = '<span id="ff3814">' + $output +'</span>';?

Comment: Because the output text may contain other content @Shiping apologies for not stating that; I will do so now

Comment: Okay. one thing you may try is to first replace \" with, say, _BSDQ_, and \' with _BSSQ_ (or some other fancy string with special characters, something you sure won't be in the text). then you put <span> and </span> around quoted phrases. then you replace _BSDQ_ with \" and _BSSQ_ with \'.

Comment: Also do think about other quotation types, that might occur in your texts. Like the English `“…”`, German `„…“` or French `»…«` quotations.

Comment: @feeela just single quotes and double quotes for now :)